# Laravel Vue: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"

Tags: bootstrap-vue, laravel-vue

Im implementing the bootstrap-vue tab in the application but when I copied one of the example im getting some error "Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"

**Example**

```
<div>
  <b-tabs
    active-nav-item-class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-danger"
    active-tab-class="font-weight-bold text-success"
    content-class="mt-3"
  >
    <b-tab title="First" active><p>I'm the first tab</p></b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Second"><p>I'm the second tab</p></b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Disabled" disabled><p>I'm a disabled tab!</p></b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
</div>
```

In the code above, when I clicked any tab, it is working in their website
but in my side getting that error.

Question: how do I fix the error  "Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"?